# Ubuntu 20.04 does not wake up after suspend on HP laptop

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, suspend, hp

I am running a new HP 14s-fq1377ng Notebook (Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 5700u with radeon graphics × 16, Graphics: AMD Renoir) and have a working dual-boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.

In Ubuntu, when I try to put my laptop to sleep by either closing the lid or selecting "suspend" the following happens: After a few seconds where it seems that nothing happens, the Notebook screen goes black as desired. Afterwards I am not able to resume to the session by pressing any key. Even pressing the power button has no effect. Only thing I can do is to press the power button for 3 seconds to shut down completely. Then I can reboot via the GRUB menu but my Ubuntu session is lost.

On the same laptop in Windows, I have no problems putting the laptop to sleep and waking it up at all.

I know that there are lots of suspend issues out there and I spent hours looking for a solution but I couldn't come up with one that suits my specific problems. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Result of

```
journalctl --system --boot=0 | egrep -i "suspend|resume|entry|exit"
```

reads

```
Okt 21 10:38:03 jansc-HP kernel: Dentry cache hash table entries: 2097152 (order: 12, 16777216 bytes, linear)
Okt 21 10:38:03 jansc-HP kernel: nvme 0000:02:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
Okt 21 10:38:03 jansc-HP anacron[695]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Okt 21 10:38:05 jansc-HP systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Okt 21 10:38:05 jansc-HP systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Okt 21 10:38:05 jansc-HP systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Okt 21 10:38:05 jansc-HP systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Okt 21 10:42:53 jansc-HP anacron[2935]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Okt 21 11:33:19 jansc-HP anacron[5518]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
```

Comment: Please add result of `journalctl --system --boot=0 | egrep -i "suspend|resume|entry|exit"`  and if it shows `BIOS update required for suspend/resume`  you know what you need ;-)  and as another suggestion: please try with 21.04. It could be that 20.04 is too old for your hardware.

Comment: I have the same problem with hp 15z-ef2000 and Ryzen 5500U.  I also spent HOURS on this with PopOS.  Here are some links with proposed solutions, none of which worked for me:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371512/unresponsive-black-screen-after-suspend; https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kernel-patch-to-solve-suspend-issue-for-amd-ryzen-laptop/61743.  PopOS has the 5.15.8 kernel, but does not fix it for me.  Now trying with Fedora and Manjaro.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around for answers and could not find anything that worked. I ended-up disabling the suspend mode by tweaking the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file.

Here are the things I changed [they were commented out before]

```
HandleHibernateKey=halt
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

This works for me until there is a real fix.