# Can't wake HP laptop up after lid close on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, suspend, hp

(I don't quite understand the difference between sleep, suspend and hibernate, and I don't know which one should be happening, but I mean the action that is supposed to be happening on lid close.)

Hello, I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with the 5.13.0-39-generic Kernel, on my new HP 15s-eq1375ng notebook with a AMD Ryzen 7 processor. I am also using the Kde Plasma desktop. I have been using Ubuntu for the past year, but I am not very good with it.

My problem is that whenever I close the lid, or use the suspend option from the GUI, the laptop seemingly suspends, but I am not able to wake it with the power button or the keyboard and the touchpad. The only way to use the laptop is to hold the power button for a few seconds to force the system to shut down, and then press it again to start it - effectively restarting it.

So far, I've tried uncommenting these lines in /etc/systemd/logind.conf and restarting, but it didn't help.

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

this is the output of `journalctl --system --boot=0 | egrep -i "suspend|resume|entry|exit"`
as someone in the comments of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370675/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-wake-up-after-suspend-on-hp-laptop) requested, but I don't really understand it.

```
Apr 01 10:33:59 calculester kernel: Dentry cache hash table entries: 2097152 (order: 12, 16777216 bytes, linear)
Apr 01 10:34:00 calculester systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 01 10:34:00 calculester systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 01 10:34:00 calculester systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 01 10:34:00 calculester systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 01 10:34:01 calculester systemd[1]: fancontrol.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 01 10:34:01 calculester systemd[1]: fancontrol.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 01 10:34:07 calculester sddm[1053]: Auth: sddm-helper exited successfully
Apr 01 10:34:07 calculester systemd-logind[857]: Session 1 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Apr 01 10:34:17 calculester systemd[1137]: systemd-exit.service: Succeeded.
Apr 01 10:34:17 calculester systemd[1137]: Finished Exit the Session.
Apr 01 10:34:17 calculester systemd[1137]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Apr 01 10:39:01 calculester anacron[816]: Normal exit (1 job run)
```

The only other things I've been able to find online have been similar problems to mine but pertaining to either earlier Linux versions, fixing the issue on windows, upgrading the Kernel to version 5.13 (which I already have) or editing "Advanced Power Management Settings" in BIOS/UEFI, which I do not have.

Other solutions suggested that the suspend state may not be supported by my hardware, but when I was using Windows the notebook didn't have any problems going to sleep and waking up. I cannot upgrade to 21.04 or to change the Distribution because the current configuration is necessary for my work.

I am assuming the problem lies in that the system cannot wake the notebook up, because pressing the caps-lock key, the one that has a light to indicate if its turned off and on, doesn't do anything.

I would be grateful for any help you could provide.